# Spawner - Did the spawn rate change?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since MC1.9 I noticed that Skeleton-spawns (in our Skeleton farm, that works with a Skeleton spawner) take forever. There is like 1 skeleton spawning per 2 minutes. Is this normal? I used to be able to get to level 30 in like 15-20 minutes on 1.8.

I also switched my server from a hoster to my own home-server, so I'm not sure if my server maybe is to slow and skips the "ticks" where new skeletons would be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I don't know if that is normal, but I do know a fix:

If you are in creative mode you can place the spawner using `/setblock` and the tags `SpawnCount` and `Delay`. Simply do:

`/setblock (x) (y) (z) minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnCount:(how many you want to spawn),Delay:(how often you want that amount to spawn)}`

A better explanation is in Dragnoz's video here:

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, but this isn't something I want to do. But thx anyways for the workaround. :)